# Shared Variable state not accurately communicated between include files

Tags: c, embedded

Programming an EFM32ZG embedded system with wireless UART capabilities.

The UART properly receives data from a wireless ground station. When it does, I simply toggle a boolean value to "true". The boolean is set in the interrupt service handler when the UART detects information in the RX buffer. To test this functionality, I instructed the microprocessor to set an LED high when it correctly decodes the packet, and it does, so I am confident that the issue is not in the receiving of UART data.

From the UART.h file I declare my boolean:

```
 `volatile bool Sweep_CW`
```

In the UART.c file I have a function that sets the value to True:

```
    if(received_packet[1] == '1' && received_packet[2] == '1'){
    Sweep_CW = true;
    ...
}
```

Another section of my code reads this boolean value. The interfacing file has the following in it's header file:

```
extern volatile bool Sweep_CW;
```

In the interfacing file's ".c" file, I have a function that will set an LED high when it reads the boolean as true. This function is called when new data is received on the UART, otherwise the CPU will wait in a loop. I am confident this part of the code works as well, as it was extensively tested.

```
...
if(Sweep_CW)
GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortC,11);
...
```

The issue: Sweep_CW is never interpreted as 'true' in the interfacing file's .c function.

Question: I feel like this should be suuuuuper easy, but it's giving me a lot of grief. Have I incorrectly setup my declarations / Am I missing something terribly obvious?

Things I've tried so far:

1) I made sure I was using the "volatile" storage class specifier - Which is very important in this case.

2) I made sure my interrupt service routine clears the correct flags once completed.

3) Reviewed material online on similar subjects:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53218/pic-global-variable-not-modified-inside-interrupt-handler

4) Took a quick nap and came back to this with a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: When do you set it false again?

Answer (score 0):

`extern volatile bool Sweep_CW;` is *the* declaration and belongs in to header file.

`volatile bool Sweep_CW;` is the definition and should only appear once in one the the source files.

Unfortunately, this alone does not explain your problems. Can you post a more complete code example that exhibits the problem.  It is difficult to analyse fro small fragments that might not even contain the relevant code.